# Exception gecko.utils.saveimage.convertimagetopng

Tags: c#, geckofx

This code is active for geckofx33 but with geckofx45 and 60 i have an exception. (Additional information: Value cannot be null. in gecko45) or (Additional information: Failed to compile script. in gecko 60). Please help me handle these exceptions.
These exceptions is relate to the funtion: Gecko.Utils.SaveImageElement.ConvertGeckoImageElementToPng(geckoWeb, image, (float)0, (float)0, 200, 70);

```
private void LoadCapcha()
        {            
            foreach (var element in geckoWeb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img"))
            {
                if (element.GetAttribute("id") == "CaptchaImage")
                {
                    Gecko.DOM.GeckoImageElement image = (Gecko.DOM.GeckoImageElement)element;
                    byte[] byteImage = Gecko.Utils.SaveImageElement.ConvertGeckoImageElementToPng(geckoWeb, image, (float)0, (float)0, 200, 70);
                    File.WriteAllBytes("test.png", byteImage);
                    pictureCapchaBox.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(byteImage));
                }
            }
        }
```

I expect the image element is displayed in pictureCapchaBox.

Comment: Yes. Hope you help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug in GeckoFX-45 that prevents you from [capturing an image element inside an iframe](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/issues/49/cant-capture-an-image-element-inside-an).

The suggested workaround is to use the `ImageCreator` class instead instead:

```
Gecko.ImageCreator ic = new Gecko.ImageCreator(GeckoWebBrowser1);
ic.CanvasGetPngImage(img.OffsetLeft, img.OffsetTop, img.Width, img.Height);
```